Multiple switch statement using advance/new type
enter image description here
I am trying to use this format for the switch statement but getting error in Eclipse, but somehow it is not throwing an error in IntelliJ. What needs to be changed?
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int switchValue = 3;
    
    switch(switchValue) {
    case 1: System.out.println("Value was 1");
    case 2: System.out.println("Value was 2");
    case 3,4,5 ->
    {
        System.out.println("Value was 3");
    }
    
    default -> System.out.println("Was not 1,2,3,4 or 5");
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Mixing of different kinds of case statements '->' and  ':' is not allowed within a switch

    at keywords.Switchhh.main(Switchhh.java:12)


IDK. Could be a language change. Could be a bug in the eclipse java compiler. Eclipse uses a custom compiler. intellij probably does too. Probably shouldn't mix styles. I would expect 1 and 2 to fall through. Which doesn't make a lot of sense. But then mixing styles is sus.

As the error message says: in a single switch statement you must use either the old approach (where label and statements are seperated by a colon :) or the new approach (where label and statement are seperated by a ->). In your case I would change case 1: to case 1 -> and case 2: to case 2 ->.

Are you sure IntelliJ doesn't give you an error message? On my machine, it puts a red underline under the offending code and says "Different case kinds used in switch". Note that Eclipse and IntelliJ use different ways of reporting syntax errors. IntelliJ does it immediately as you type the code, without first having to compile it.

As the Java Language specification says it (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11.1): A switch block can consist of either: Switch rules, which use -> to introduce either a switch rule expression, a switch rule block, or a switch rule throw statement; or Switch labeled statement groups, which use : to introduce switch labeled block statements.

the error message is pretty clear (IMHO): "Mixing of different kinds of case statements '->' and ':' is not allowed within a switch" (BTW if you use the labeled statements ':', then each must end with a break or return unless you want it to fall-through to the next one)

Just like Eclipse, IntelliJ will produce an error, it will just do it in a different way: IntelliJ will produce the error in the Build Output ("java: different case kinds used in the switch"), and not produce a runnable program, while the Eclipse ecj compiler will still create a runnable program that fails with a runtime exception at the point where you had the syntax error(s) (essentially removing the error(s) from the program code, and replacing it/them with the exception(s))..

Note that although according to Eclipse, you can't mix case statement types in the same switch block, you can mix the two switch block types as long as they are completely separated within the code. The following works in Eclipse (Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0)) (although I can't think of a reason to do it).
switch (switchValue) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Value was 1");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Value was 2");
        break;
    default : {
        switch (switchValue) {
            case 1, 2, 3 -> System.out.println("Value was 3");
            default -> System.out.println("Was not 1,2,3,4 or 5");
        }
    }
}



Mixing of different kinds of case statements '->' and ':' is not
allowed within a switch

It's like the error states, don't mix the ":" and "->"
switch (switchValue) {
    case 1 -> System.out.println("Value was 1");
    case 2 -> System.out.println("Value was 2");
    case 3, 4, 5 -> System.out.println("Value was 3");
    default -> System.out.println("Was not 1,2,3,4 or 5");
}

